# Is there any way to view PDF layers online

Tags: pdf

Is there any API to view PDF layer online just like view layers in Adobe Acrobat.
Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the company I work for supports full PDF viewing online (completely client side) on all modern browsers and devices, including color separations, overprint simulation, and layers.

You can open any PDF in this [online demo](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/pdf-layers) and interactively turn on/off layers. You can check the network panel to see that your PDF never leaves your machine, everything is done client side.